# Is this valid for convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt[n]{3} - 1$ converge or diverge?

**Hints please**

I have that $0 \le \sqrt[n]{3}  - 1 \le 1$

Does this help?

Comment: No, the information you have does not help. This series diverges, and you need the comparison test for help.

Answer (score 4):

We have $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n <e<3$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Hence

$$ \sqrt[n]{3} - 1> \frac{1}{n}$$

for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$ we have
$$3^x-1 = e^{(\log 3) x}-1=1+(\log 3)x+\frac{(\log 3)^2x^2}{2}+\ldots -1> (\log 3)x $$
Hence
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\sqrt[n]{3}-1 \ge\log3 \cdot \sum_{n\ge1}\frac1n$$